# Sleeping mysql processes not clearing

Tags: mysql, apache, cakephp, xampp

I keep getting sleeping mysql processes while my users are using my CakePHP application.

This is a problem because access to the application is frozen (loading indefinitely) on that user's computer. Users on other computers do not seem to be affected when one user's application is frozen. The only way to clear this problem for that particular user is to restart the apache service on the server (which isn't ideal as I run multiple button applications on this server).

After waiting more than 5 minutes, the user gets this error, which seems to be generated by our proxy server.

`ERROR`

`The requested URL could not be retrieved`

`While trying to retrieve the URL: [no URL]`

`The following error was encountered:`

`Read Timeout`

`The system returned:`

```
[No Error]
```

`A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.`

`Your cache administrator is root.`

I'm struggling to determine what is causing the query to "fall asleep", and therefore fix it.

In my opinion, there are three options of where the problem could lie:

1. MySQL
2. CakePHP
3. Apache

Any ideas?

My `SHOW PROCESSLIST` query results is show below:

```
        ID  User        Host            Database        Command Time    Status  SQL query
Kill    330 instrument  localhost:1267  instrument_2012 Sleep   5235    ---     ---
Kill    331 pma         localhost:1270  None            Sleep   0       ---     ---
Kill    332 root        localhost:1271  mysql           Query   0       ---     SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

#### Notes

- I'm not using persistent connections.
- All users connect to the database through the CakePHP application.
- The application connects to the database using 'instrument' as the username.
- Restarting the mysql service (and not the apache service) has no affect.
- CPU usage goes up to 50% from <1% after freezing, until apache service is restarted

#### EDIT

I've limited the number of records I retrieve in the query to 800 and the response time is 12 seconds. When I retrieve 1200 records, response time is 72 seconds. When I retrieve 1600 records, response time is 132 seconds.

Why is the response time increasing so rapidly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is issue of mysql, but php/apache.Can you check what is name of process causing CPU high usage?

Sleep means that worker thread is idle for user's session, because user does not close connection yet.BTW error message comes from squid proxy because target web site did not respond in some time period.

Comment: In task manager:
Image Name: httpd.exe *32 
User name: SYSTEM 
CPU: 50
Memory Usage: 741,120k

Comment: More information is needed on this.How is configured your XAMP in terms of PHP, using mod_php or CGI/FCGI?Does it crashes after some time period?If yes you are able to create crash report/dump which can be analyzed in debugger.But simply said, this has nothing to do with mysql at all.

Comment: I don't have mod_php, but I do have mod_cgi. It crashes with queries that return a large number of results (>500 rows). However, running the query directly on the database executes normally. It doesn't crash as such, the web page just never loads, i.e. loading spinner just keeps spinning. It would be more helpful if it timed out eventually, which it doesn't seem to do. So, I'm not sure how to create a crash report from that. If you need more information, just ask. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to research in CakePHP support?I don't even know this framework, but generally said you can use debugger to attach to php CGI worker process and debug it when needed.At least you can have call stack which can be very useful.Be sure to use debug checked binaries with symbols available from PHP site.

Comment: Nobody else seems to have had the same problem in CakePHP forums/support etc. Thanks for your help. I'll try to debug it that way. At least I know it's not mysql now. :)

Comment: Correction, it would seem I do load in mod_php.